# Line chart connectnulls but not all nulls

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart were in some cases I manually assign a null value so that point is not represented in the graphic.
I use the connect nulls property to connect the points before and after them.

http://jsfiddle.net/fpanci/q72CG/

My problem is that I need to do that with some nulls but not with all of them.

Is there a way to tell highcharts not to connect one point?
Probably change that null with some special value?

For example, here I want the chart ending at 29 and restart in 30.

```
series: [{
    connectNulls: true,
    data:[20,27,35,null,29, null ,30,null,22,null]
}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make these "split" sections into different series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this differently.

1) set `connectNulls: false`
2) specify your data as x,y pairs

This way, when you don't need a data point, you simply don't specify anything for that point - the line will automatically connect to the next x,y pair.

When you need a break, then you specify your null value.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/q72CG/3/

If you want to make sure all the categories show, whether or not there is enough data, set your x axis max accordingly as well.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is? The two solutions are perfectly compatible...you just need to provide the x value for each data point you want displayed, keeping in mind that the x value is the INDEX value, not the value shown in the category label (ie, 0.2 = 0, 0.5 = 1, etc...)

Comment: Sorry, your right. I didn't understand the solution.
Thanks!